# Do I need a comma here?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Sentence: He walked to his friends that were in the store to talk to them.

Do I need a comma after "store"?

Thanks.

Comment: For this type of question you need to be on the *English Language Learners* site.

Comment: Adding a comma adds emphasis to the reason (to talk to 'them').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. The problem is that the comma slows the sentence down. That's why I wanted to know whether it was necessary, but it seems like it is not.

Comment: It's an **advantage** that you have a device that allows you to add a pause if you wish to.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I certainly agree. However, my story has too many pauses, and I think that this pause is unnecessary. I will definitely use the pause when suitable in the future. Thanks again.